# mysql SET or linking table

Tags: mysql, database, join, set

I have little disccusion and want to hear your opinion.
If we have 2 tables:

```
   NEWS:
     -id
     -content
     -...
     -...


   website:
     -id
     -name
     -...
```

These tables are for 1 website for several countries (5-6). Where in website table we keep information for the website..like url,prefix,contact info ...
And now to the question how it will be better to connect those 2 tables.With 1 link table like this:

```
          news_website:
            news_id
            website_id
```

where we check the news in which websites is or to create one more field type 'SET' in NEWS table. 
My opinion is that if we create one extra field would be better because we are decreasing the queries.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If one news belongs to multiple website then prefer mapping table news_website if not then add new colum news table which refer to web site. Adding set column in news table for multiple websit is not maintainable